# Is there a way to find dimensions of a frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to append an image to a frame I have. However, I have many frames within each other so I don't know what the dimensions of this frame are.
Is there any function or anything that will output the dimensions of the frame like "100x500", for example?

Thanks

Comment: `def dimension(frame): return f"{frame.winfo_width()}x{frame.winfo_height()}"`.

Comment: Alternatively `def dimension(frame): return f"{frame.winfo_reqwidth()}x{frame.winfo_reqheight()}"`. For more info please look at [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20201112021403/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Every widget has the methods `winfo_width` and `winfo_height` which return the current dimensions of the widget. You can also use `winfo_reqwidth` and `winfo_reqheight` to get the *requested* width and height. The two can be different if the size of the widget changes due to how it is managed (eg: when using `sticky` with `grid`, or `fill` with `pack`.

If the window has not yet actually been rendered, the width and height returned by `winfo_width` and `winfo_height` will be 1.